# How to initialize 2D list to be able to append sublists?

Tags: python

My code is as follows:

```
l = [[]] * 10
for i in range(10):
  l[i] += [0]
```

I need a 10 x 1 matrix of zeros.

It doesn't work as expected because the list comprises references to the same variable. As a result, I am getting a 10 x 10 matrix.

How to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
l = [[] for _ in range(10)]
```

This will create 10 independent sublists.  You can then modify any of them without affecting the others.  (The use of `_` for the loop variable is a common Python convention for an unused loop variable.)

Here's an example of how modifying one sublist leaves the others unaffected:

```
>>> l[2].append(5)
>>> l
[[], [], [5], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>>
```

Comment: if we simply do `[[]]*10` that also accomplishes the same task right? would you like to add it to your answer?]

Comment: @lifezbeautiful No, `[[]]*10` doesn't work, because it creates 10 references to the *same* list.  This was pointed out in OP's post.  You need the `[]` to be evaluated 10 times, resulting in the creation of 10 sublists, rather than just once.

Answer (score 0):

There multiples ways to obtain what you are looking for :

There some possibilites

> Using list comprehension

```py
L = [[0] for k in range (10)]
```

> Using numpy np.zeros function

```py
L = np.zeros((10,1)).tolist() # if you want a list and not an array
```

Comment: `np.zeros` *doesn't create a list of lists*

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga  Fixed the issue